# DHTMLx - Cookie getting reset during onXLE event

Tags: javascript, cookies, dhtmlx

So lets say I have a grid where I am saving a state in a cookie after hiding one of the element from a column. Now after I reload the page, the onXLE event seems to be reset this cookie for some reason. Anyway, I can preserve this cookie?

Another option I had in mind is saving the cookie in some kind of a global variable and then passing it back right after the onXLE event is called.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably in the onXLE event (or a callback function of the load() method) at first you are saving the cookies state, and that loading, while you need to load the states and then save them. Could you please your using snippet of a code.

Comment: sorry its tough to paste the code. Doesn't onXLE by default first loads the state and then saves the cookie? If not, is there any other DHTMLx function that I can use to make sure this happens first?

Comment: there are no such functions. If the problem still occurs fro you please, provide a snippet of your code so the p[roblem can be reproduced locally